# what does this template definition mean in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading some c++ code, and the code list below makes me really confused.
I can guess it tries to define a specialized template, which tries to trait the input args types. But I got a few question:
**the first template looks like both deriving and template specialization, if it is deriving, how can a struct derived from itself? if it is a template specialization, where is the template defination?**

```
template<typename F>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<decltype(&F::operator())>
{};

template<typename R, typename C, typename ... Args>
struct function_traits<R(C::*)(Args...) const> {
    template<size_t i>
    struct arg
    {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
    };
};
```

Comment: where did you find the code?

Comment: @user463035818 an open source code, which tries to implement a variant-like thing. it can work, I have ran it.

Comment: Not from itself: `function_traits<F>` and `function_traits<decltype(&F::operator())>` are different types, like `struct A` and `struct B`.

Comment: you dont want to tell which project it is? I mean how can we know where to find the base template if all we have is the code you show here ;)

Comment: HI @D.pz, For your question how can a struct derived from itself. The thing here is that function_traits<decltype(&F::operator())> and function_traits<F> are two different types.

Comment: @user463035818 http://files.cnblogs.com/qicosmos/TaskCppV1.1.zip   there is some error in this code(which the author uploaded), so it may not be successfully compiled, but I have fix these error

Comment: @user463035818: primary template is the first one, you don't have to look for it anywhere...

Comment: @Jaa-c yeah I got it, nevertheless imho it is mandatory to give a reference when posting code that you didnt write yourself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first declaration is just a definition of the primary template for `struct function_traits`. Note that there's no problem with a particular specialisation of a template being derived from a different specialisation of that template (as long as there are no loops). Remember that each specialisation of a class template is a distinct, unrelated type.

The second declaration simply introduces a partial specialisation for function types, whose instantiations will likely get used as the base-class for the primary template (since the primary template derives from a specialisation whose template argument is a member function type).

Comment: The definition of a primary template looks like a perfectly valid `void* ptr = &ptr;`.

Comment: `template<typename F>`  
`struct function_traits : public function_traits<decltype(&F::operator())>`  
`{};` does that mean, the `function_traits`before : is the primary template, the `function_traits<decltype(&F::operator())>` is the primary template's specialized template, and at the same time, the primary template can be derived from its specialized template?

Comment: @Evg your explaination is very clear, I seems to understand, thanks

Comment: @D.pz Except it isn't what this is.  templates classes are factories of types.  So it states that the factory `template<class F>struct function_traits` generates a type that in turn inherits from what `function_traits<decltype(&F::operator())>` would produce.  This recursion isn't guaranteed to be infinite, because this is only the primary specialization; so long as this process terminates with a different specialization that isn't recursive there is no problem.